# How to find when a user is started and ended a session on computer based on Windows Event Log?

Tags: windows, security, logging, events

As part of some research I need to collect working hours of all the workers in my company. I have no code execution of their PCs, but I can collected any type of event log from their computer.

I need to determinate when user is logging in (starting the session) and when the session ends.

I believe that it's related to `Security.evtx` log.

After a bit googling I have found that I can determinate session start (logon) by the [`4624`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624) event log id, so that part is pretty easy. The problem comes when I try to figure out when the user session is closed.

I see 3 main reasons that can cause session disconnect -

1. screen timeout and then the pc is auto locking.
2. Manual WinKey + L.
3. system shutdown/sleep (this part is very easy to determinate based on security log).

After googling I found that the relevant event id for `logoff` is [4634](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4634), but after looking on my Security log I saw that it's very common log and that it's not really indicative, for example - when I unlock my windows there are 2 logs of 4624 and then comes a 4634 log (??) without any reason.

So after a bit more googling I found that I can determinate  `WinKey + L` with [4647](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4647) event id.

After a lot of research and googling I still didn't found a solution for finding out when the user session is timed out and the desktop is automatically locked... and this part is very important as the workers never lock their computer, just leave it open and after some timeout ( 15 minutes +-) the computer is automatically locking and I need to figure out how to see that from the event log (one of my ideas was to check if there is a log about `LogonUI.exe` creation, but unfortunately the default audit configuration is not showing me such log.

Any ideas how can I see from the event log when user is idle and the desktop is auto locking ?

I can get any event log, but I can't change the audit configs and I cannot execute code on their computers.

Comment: Hope this vedio can help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B04-RXMtWY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you can't log when `LogonUI.exe` appears, you can observe the security events it triggers. Specifically, when the lock screen appears, it enumerates the local group memberships of each local user. You can therefore look for event 4798 with a `Data` tag named `CallerProcessName` with a value of `C:\Windows\System32\LogonUI.exe` to identify when the lock screen is shown.

Unfortunately, if the inactive user has a screensaver, the lock screen will not be shown until the computer is woken up. No event appears in the Security log until then. The `Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon/Operational` log, however, is enabled by default at least on Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise and logs many relevant events. Conveniently, it's in terms of logon sessions, which are higher-level than the tokens tracked by the Security log. Events come in start/finish pairs, so you can filter to either event 811 or 812. The `UserID` attribute of the standard `Security` tag under `System` provides the SID of the affected user. The `Data` tag named `Event` specifies the session event type:

2. logon
3. logoff
4. lock (regardless of automatic or manual)
5. unlock
6. screensaver start
7. screensaver stop

If there is a screensaver, session event 6 will be logged when inactivity is detected and events 7 then 4 will be logged later when the computer wakes up to the lock screen, unless the user wakes the computer within the few-second grace period, in which case only event 7 will be logged and the computer will not lock. If there is no screensaver, event 4 will be logged immediately when inactivity is detected and the computer locks.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you very much. Trying to figure out the difference between event id 811 and 812 (and again cant find any info in google). Maybe you know also what ks the difference?

Comment: Event 811 is logged before Winlogon notifies other system components of the session state change; event 812 is logged after the notification is processed. It seems that only milliseconds pass between these events, so it doesn't really matter which you pick.